# Script jQuery não carrega em dispositivos móveis

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Estou com uma dúvida. Tenho um site em wordpress, e somente em uma página não está carregando o jQuery, e apenas no mobile! Alguém pode me ajudar? Segue o script que não está abrindo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('.close').click(function(){

            jQuery(this).closest('.dinamicContent').removeClass('abredinamicContent');
            jQuery(this).closest('html').removeClass('scrollHtml');
            jQuery(this).closest('.dinamicContent').html( " " );

        });

        $('.fundoFecha').click(function(){

            jQuery(this).closest('.dinamicContent').removeClass('abredinamicContent');
            jQuery(this).closest('html').removeClass('scrollHtml');
            jQuery(this).closest('.dinamicContent').html( " " );

        });

        jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        jQuery(".mudaPost").click(function(){
            var post_link = jQuery(this).attr("href");
            jQuery(".innerPortfolio").delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
            jQuery(".dinamicContent").html("content loading");
            jQuery(".dinamicContent").load(post_link);

            return false;
        });

        jQuery('#statusdos').delay(700).fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
        jQuery('#preloaderdos').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Já tentou debugar pelo chrome? Plugando o celular no computador, abrindo o chrome e indo colocando como endereço `chrome://inspect` dá pra usar o console e etc., mas com a navegação do celular. Assim você pode ver se tem alguma mensagem de erro :)